# Is it okay to place frontend and backend of the application in same pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I just want to know is there any performance wise issue, if I place Angular part of my application in one container and Nodejs part of application in another container in same pod?

Is it okay to create structure like this or will it create problems.